# AWS Appsync: how to write mutation update for increment by 1

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I wrote a mutation query and updated value in dynamo successfully as below:

```
mutation update {
    updateTodo(input:
        id: “xxxxxxxxx”
        completed: true
    }) {
        id title completed
    }
}
```

But in table ToDo, I have another field `quantity` (Int) where I want to increase by 1 (quantity ++ ). How to write a mutation query to achieve it.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AppSync resolver for the mutation you would be able to add on to the DDB UpdateExpression with something like 'SET quantity = quantity + :val' where :val is your increment size (e.g. 1).

more here w/ examples: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html